# Dodecahedron doesn't display correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, geometry

I'm attempting to draw a dodecahedron by hand (without the glut function call), but I'm having issues getting the faces to display correctly (I'm also not using back face culling so I understand the math behind it) and when I try to apply transformations onto the shape using the keyboard, it has no effect.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib> //just in case
#include <stdlib.h> //just in case
#include <math.h> //powers, square roots, and trig functions are used
#include <gl/glut.h>
#ifndef magic
#define magic 1.618033989
#endif
#ifndef magic2
#define magic2 0.618033989
#endif
#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.1415926535
#endif
int faces[12][5] = 
{   
    {0, 16, 2, 10, 8}, 
    {0, 8, 4, 14, 12},
    {16, 17, 1, 12, 0},
    {1, 9, 11, 3, 17},
    {1, 12, 14, 5, 9},
    {2, 13, 15, 6, 10},
    {13, 3, 17, 16, 2},
    {3, 11, 7, 15, 13},
    {4, 8, 10, 6, 18},
    {14, 5, 19, 18, 4},
    {5, 19, 7, 11, 9},
    {15, 7, 19, 18, 6}
};
double points[20][3] = 
{
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, -1},
    {1, -1, 1},
    {1, -1, -1},
    {-1, 1, 1},
    {-1, 1, -1},
    {-1, -1, 1},
    {-1, -1, -1},
    {0, magic2, magic},
    {0, magic2, -magic},
    {0, -magic2, magic},
    {0, -magic2, -magic},
    {magic2, magic, 0},
    {magic2, -magic, 0},
    {-magic2, magic, 0},
    {-magic2, -magic, 0},
    {magic, 0, magic2},
    {magic, 0, -magic2},
    {-magic, 0, magic2},
    {-magic, 0, -magic2}
};
/*double radians(double d){ return d * PI / 180; }
double up[3][3] =
{
    {cos(radians(0.01)), -sin(radians(0.01)), 0},
    {sin(radians(0.01)), cos(radians(0.01)), 0},
    {0, 0, 1}
}; //up rotation matrix
double down[3][3] = 
{
    {cos(radians(-0.01)), -sin(radians(-0.01)), 0},
    {sin(radians(-0.01)), cos(radians(-0.01)), 0},
    {0, 0, 1}
}; //down rotation matrix
double left[3][3] = 
{
    {cos(radians(-0.01)), 0, sin(radians(-0.01))},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {-sin(radians(-0.01)), 0, cos(radians(-0.01))}
}; //left rotation matrix
double right[3][3] = 
{
    {cos(radians(0.01)), 0, sin(radians(0.01))},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {-sin(radians(0.01)), 0, cos(radians(0.01))}
}; //right rotation matrix
*/
void cross(double a[], double b[], double vec1[]){ //gets the cross product of a and b and stores it in vec1
    vec1[0] = a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1];
    vec1[1] = a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2];
    vec1[2] = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
}
void getNormal(int n, int m, int x, double vec1[]){ //gets the normal vector
    double a[] = {points[m][0] - points[n][0], points[m][1] - points[n][1], points[m][2] - points[n][2]};
    double b[] = {points[m][0] - points[x][0], points[m][1] - points[x][1], points[m][2] - points[x][2]};
    cross(a, b, vec1);
}
double dot(double a[], double b[]){ //dot product
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2];
}
double mag(double a[]){ //magnitude of given vector
    return sqrt(pow(a[0], 2) + pow(a[1], 2) + pow(a[2], 2));
}
bool isForwardFacing(int face[5]){ 
    double vec1[3];
    getNormal(face[0], face[1], face[2], vec1); //vec1 is the normal vector
    double vec2[] = {points[face[1]][0], points[face[1]][1], points[face[1]][2]};
    double test = dot(vec1, vec2) / (mag(vec1) * mag(vec2));
    if(test > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
//these rotations rotate the shape by 0.01 degrees
/*void rotateUp(){ //positive rotation about z axis
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            points[i][j] = points[i][0] * up[0][j] + points[i][1] * up[1][j] + points[i][2] * up[2][j];
        }
    }
}
void rotateLeft(){ //negative rotation about y axis
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            points[i][j] = points[i][0] * left[0][j] + points[i][1] * left[1][j] + points[i][2] * left[2][j];
        }
    }
}
void rotateDown(){ //negative rotation about z axis
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            points[i][j] = points[i][0] * down[0][j] + points[i][1] * down[1][j] + points[i][2] * down[2][j];
        }
    }
}
void rotateRight(){ //positive rotation about y axis
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            points[i][j] = points[i][0] * right[0][j] + points[i][1] * right[1][j] + points[i][2] * right[2][j];
        }
    }
} */
void myFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key == 'w' || key == 'W'){
        glPopMatrix();
        glRotated(0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
             glPushMatrix();
    }
    else if(key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
        glPopMatrix();
        glRotated(0.01, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
             glPushMatrix();
    }
    else if(key == 's' || key == 'S'){
        glPopMatrix();
        glRotated(0.01, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
             glPushMatrix();
    }
    else if(key == 'd' || key == 'D'){
        glPopMatrix();
        glRotated(0.01, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
             glPushMatrix();
    }
}
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-3.0, 3.0, -3.0, 3.0, -3.0, 3.0);

    glPushMatrix();

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        if(isForwardFacing(faces[i])){
            glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                glVertex3dv(points[faces[i][x]]);
            glEnd();
            glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                glVertex3dv(points[faces[i][x]]);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //boilerplate stuff
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("Dodecahedron");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(myFunc); //animation function
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As this question stands, it's a request of the form “here is my code, please fix it for me”. This is generally frowned upon, since on the one side it's requiesting SO members to solve your problems for you, and on the other side it means that this question and its answers likely won't benefit anyone but you. I did answer the question in this case, since I had hoped that the core problem would be a geometric one, but the coordinates work out just fine, so in hindsight I consider this a not particularly useful question. Hence my downvote. In the future, concentrate on *one single issue*.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. You are always reinitializing the model view matrix in the display function. Therefore any matrix modifications in the keyboard function will be without effect.
2. You probably want to execute the `glOrtho` call after `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` since you want to set the projection there.
3. You might as well drop all that pushing and popping of matrices, since you only ever modify the current matrix, and never need to restore a previous state.
4. You need to `glutPostRedisplay` in the keyboard function to trigger a redisplay.
5. You are rotating by 0.01° which is a very small amount. Try 10° for starters, adjust once you are happy with all the rest.
6. You should be drawing `GL_LINE_STRIP` not `GL_LINES` since you don't repeat vertices. But even then you need to repeat the first vertex of each pentagon to close it.
7. Your `isForwardFacing` function doesn't take the current model view matrix into account, so it will cause faces to be missing. I guess I'd leave face culling to OpenGL, or simply render all faces.
8. If you disable your forward-facing check, your might get objects from the back of the scene drawn over those from the front since you did not `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`.
9. You don't take the aspect ratio of the window into account for your `glOrtho` call.
10. The header should be called `<GL/glut.h>` not `<gl/glut.h>`. On OS where case makes a difference for file names, this is important.
11. `myFunc` is a rather undescriptive name for a function.

You can try something like this:

```
void myFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key == 'w' || key == 'W')
        glRotated(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                         // changed
    else if(key == 'a' || key == 'A')
        glRotated(10.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);                        // changed
    else if(key == 's' || key == 'S')
        glRotated(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);                        // changed
    else if(key == 'd' || key == 'D')
        glRotated(10.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);                         // changed
    // all glPopMatrix() and glPushMatrix() calls removed       // removed
    glutPostRedisplay();                                        // added
}

void reshape(int w, int h){                                     // added
    double aspect = double(w) / double(h);                      // added
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                    // added
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                                // added
    glOrtho(-3.0 * aspect, 3.0 * aspect, -3.0, 3.0, -3.0, 3.0); // changed
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // rotations apply to this
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         // changed
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        // if (!isForwardFacing(faces[i])) continue;            // removed
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            glVertex3dv(points[faces[i][x]]);
        glEnd();
        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);                                 // changed
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            glVertex3dv(points[faces[i][x]]);
        glVertex3dv(points[faces[i][0]]);                       // added
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //boilerplate stuff
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("Dodecahedron");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);                                   // added
    glutKeyboardFunc(myFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```